# Issues with programmatic Bulk load using SSTableLoader

Tags: cassandra

I referred an [article](https://medium.com/@rako/spark-and-cassandras-sstable-loader-ed55f6e67d17) to implement SSTable bulk load using spark to my 3-node local C* cluster setup using CCM. I'm seeing a bunch of exceptions. I do not see data getting loaded in the table. Could someone please help with this?

Here is the relevant Java code snippet:

```
        conf.set("cassandra.output.thrift.address", "127.0.0.1");
        conf.set("cassandra.output.thrift.port", "9160");

        SSTableLoader loader = new SSTableLoader(ssTablesDir, new CqlBulkRecordWriter.ExternalClient(conf), new OutputHandler.LogOutput());
        loader.stream();
```

Log: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/L9TpV8Mi)

Comment: What is the cluster's version of Cassandra?

Comment: @Aaron it is 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here are these lines:

```
conf.set("cassandra.output.thrift.address", "127.0.0.1");
conf.set("cassandra.output.thrift.port", "9160");
```

This is designed to connect to Cassandra using the Thrift protocol on port 9160.  Thrift was deprecated in the Cassandra project in version 3.0, and completely removed in Cassandra 4.0.

To make this work, you'll need to connect to Cassandra with its native binary protocol on port 9042.  Spark *should* allow you to do that.  If not, you'll need to find tools that are designed to work with recent versions of Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks for your response Aaron. Do you think bulk loading should still be possible using SSTableLoader C* API or the behavior would be more of like using spark-cassandra-connector?

Comment: @userkn So it looks like the SSTableLoader can connect to Cassandra on 9042 via native binary.  I think you're ok to still use that, but I haven't heard of anyone doing anything with it in a while.  Whereas the Spark Connector should be pretty up-to-date...looks like it was updated about 2 months ago.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I tried doing what you've suggested. I'm facing some issues. I've mentioned all the details over here : https://pastebin.com/4ve7rUNH because of Stackoverflow character limitations. Would really appreciate your guidance. Thanks!

Comment: @userkn So you should be using on the most-recent driver.  TBH, I'm not sure how well the Bulk SSTableLoader will run on the newer versions of Cassandra.  Other than to say make sure you're using a valid username/password (for the auth error).  Perhaps using the Spark Connector is the way to go here?

Comment: @userkn Not sure what you're trying to do, but the newer DSBulk tool might help you, too.  https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/dsbulkCmd.html